# SSH not working after OSX 10.10.4 upgrade (vagrant)

Tags: macos, ssh, vagrant, osx-yosemite

I upgraded to 10.10.4 this morning and after I had upgraded, when I attempted to SSH into a local Vagrant dev box, it resulted in access denied too many authentication attempts.

Comment: Have you seen the Stack Overflow [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help)? It'll help you figure out what subjects are on topic for this site, as well as how to ask specific questions that receive precise answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ssh-add -D` to delete all your keys from the SSH agent.

Then add them again using `ssh-add -k path_to_to_key`

I had the same issue with Vagrant and this fixed the problem.